# Celery queue task if execution going on

Tags: python, celery, message-queue, task-queue

Assume I have a function defined like this:

```
def some_long_computation():
  # Execute a process using subprocess.call()
```

The above function `some_long_computation` can be called only once at a time. If something else tries to call this function while this is executing, then it should be queued up and called only when the previous process finishes executing.

Is Celery capable of performing this?

If no, is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Read this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/8wzwNO7RQfU